# $P(x)=x^3-y^2+y+1$ - Roots in $\mathbb{Q}[y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I would like to show that $P(x)=x^3-y^2+y+1$ doesn't have roots as a polynomial with variable $x$ and coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}[y]$ (i.e. $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]=\mathbb{Q}[y][x]$).

Could anyone solve this problem without using explicitly the rational root theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P(f(y))=0$ then $f^3(y)=y^2-(y+1)$, and $3\deg f\ne 2$.